# Python / Attributes between methods of a class

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new in Python and I'm trying to get my head around how are managed attributes between methods of a class.

In the following example, I'm trying to modify a list in the method "regex" and use it afterwards in another method "printsc".

The "regex" part works without issues, but the attribute "self.mylist" is not updated so when I call "printsc" the result is "None".

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mylist = None

    def regex(self, items):
        self.mylist = []
        for item in items:
            if re.match(r"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$", item):
                self.mylist.append("IP:" + item)
            else:
                self.mylist.append("DNS:" + item)
        return self.mylist

    def printsc(self):
        print(self.mylist)

items = ['192.168.0.1', 'hostname1', '10.0.1.15', 'server.local.fr']

MyClass().regex(items)
MyClass().printsc()
```

What am I missing ? What is the best way to achieve this goal ?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do MyClass(), it returns you an object.. And you are calling your methods on the object. Since you are doing it twice, each time a new object is created and regex and printsc are called on different objects.

what you should do is

```
myObj = MyClass()
myObj.regex(items)
myObj.printsc()
```

Comment: So simple... Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you do:

```py
MyClass().regex(items)
MyClass().printsc()
```

You are creating 2 separate instances of MyClass, each of which will have a different `.mylist` attribute.

Either mylist is an instance attribute, and then this will work:

```py
instance = MyClass()
instance.regex(items)
instance.printsc()
```

Or, if you want to share .mylist across instances, it should be
a class attribute:

```py
class MyClass():
    class_list = None
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        

    def regex(self, items):
        cls = self.__class__
        if cls.class_list is None:
            cls.class_list = []
        for item in items:
            if re.match(r"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$", item):
                cls.class_list.append("IP:" + item)
            else:
                cls.class_list.append("DNS:" + item)
        return cls.class_list

    def printsc(self):
        # Going throuhgh `.__class__.` is actually optional for 
        # reading an attribute - if it is not in the instance
        # Python will fetch it from the class instead.
        # i.e. ,  the line bellow would work with `self.class_list`
        print(self.__class__.class_list)
```

This way, the list persists across different instances of the class, as you try to do in your example.

Comment: Thanks @jsbueno, it could be useful as well to share the list across instances

Answer (score 0):

You should create an object of the class:

```py
a = MyClass()
a.regex(items)
a.printsc()

>>> ['IP:192.168.0.1', 'DNS:hostname1', 'IP:10.0.1.15', 'DNS:server.local.fr']
```